# nginx default_site doesn't appear to be working

Tags: linux, nginx, docker, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've got nginx running in docker as a reverse proxy and have been for some time - and it works wonderfully, short of one little issue I've recently seen crop up.

**What I'd like:** when a user gets to my nginx server and there isn't a .conf file specified for the URL, either 404/444 or some other HTTP response that drops the connection.

**What I'm seeing:** when a user navigates to sudomain.url.com and that subdomain isn't specified in any of my *.conf files, nginx uses the first conf file it finds - ignoring the default.conf. Find my details below.

Any other tips/tricks you can provide would be awesome as well!

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /etc/nginx/log/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
} 


http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /etc/nginx/log/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  70;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

default.conf:

```
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 444;
}

server {
  server_name _;
  listen 443 default_server;
  return 444;
}
```

Example of a conf file (there are maybe a dozen of these):

```
server {
  listen sub.domain.com:80;
  server_name sub.domain.com;
  return 302 https://sub.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen sub.domain.com:443;
  server_name sub.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/keys/ssl.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/keys/ssl.key;

  ssl on;
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC4-SHA';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/keys/dhparams.pem;

  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.1.4:81;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Comment: is your default.conf being placed in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf?

Comment: Yes, I should note that all conf files are in /etc/nginx/conf.d/, which should be included in `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tested this but my gut feeling is that your listen directives shouldn't contain a host name. They should contain the IP address of the interface you want to be listening on and the port you want to be listening to. Then for each different port/IP combination you can specify one of them as the default.

Only **after** resolving which IP address did the request go to and which port was it on, nginx begins to actually process the request. The first step here is to check the Host header, if it finds a matching server block for the value of the host header then that's where it should route. If it doesn't find one then it should route to the default.

If there is no host header being received then, I think, in more recent versions of nginx it will drop the request, however it would previously just handle this by sending to the default server for the IP/port combo.

Below is an nginx.conf which gives me working endpoints for named servers and returns 404 for everything else. Due to HSTS headers you need to hit test.se{1,2,3,4}.home-v.ind.in to see it work or you will just get back a browser error.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes      auto;

error_log             stderr notice;
pid                   /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include                   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type              application/octet-stream;
  sendfile                  on; 
  tcp_nopush                on;
  keepalive_timeout         300s;
  ssl_certificate           /etc/pki/nginx/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/pki/nginx/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam               /etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem;
  ssl_protocols             TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers               EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_buffer_size           1400;
  ssl_session_timeout       1d;
  ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:50m;  
  ssl_stapling              on;
  ssl_stapling_verify       on;
  ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/pki/nginx/fullchain.pem;
  add_header                "Cache-Control" "no-transform";
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
  resolver                  8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 216.146.35.35 216.146.36.36 valid=60s;
  resolver_timeout          2s;

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name test.se1.home-v.ind.in;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location /.well-known { satisfy any; allow all; try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }
    location /robots.txt { satisfy any; allow all; add_header Content-Type text/plain; return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"; }
    location / { satisfy any; allow all; add_header Content-Type text/plain; return 200 "Test Site 1"; }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name test.se2.home-v.ind.in;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location /.well-known { satisfy any; allow all; try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }
    location /robots.txt { satisfy any; allow all; add_header Content-Type text/plain; return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"; }
    location / { satisfy any; allow all; add_header Content-Type text/plain; return 200 "Test Site 2"; }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location /.well-known { satisfy any; allow all; try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }
    location / { return 404; }
  }

}
```

Comment: I can remove the hostnames, they are in there for testing (something I read online) - originally it looked more like this: `listen 80;`

In either case (with and without), the conf files work when you point to them - using sub.domain.com uses the correct conf file

Comment: Well I'm stumped then, I'll post up a working sample that works on a server I've spun up listening to test.se1.home-v.ind.in, test.se2.home-v.ind.in, test.se3.home-v.ind.in and test.se4.home-v.ind.in se1 and se2 have proper listeners and everything else returns a 404.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for your help! Looking forward to comparing configs to see where I may be going wrong here.

Comment: updated my answer with a nginx.conf which serves multiple sites, some redirecting to actual pages, while all others redirect to 404.